# Trying to overwrite Bootstrap table-striped color in LESS not applying?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to make a common CSS class in my LESS file that inherits from Bootstrap's table. If I take the default it works fine but I would like to change the color of the striped rows. Doing some research I found some code that should work but it's not applying. Actually it's overwriting the default Bootstrap .table-striped and doesn't even show the normal white background color.

```
.vtc-table{
    .table;
    .table-condensed;
    .table-bordered; 
    .table-hover;
    .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td {
        background-color: antiquewhite;
    }
    th {
        background-color: #2FA4E7;
        color: white;
    } 
}
```

I'm just calling the common class at the table level.

```
<table class="vtc-table">
```

**UPDATE**

Great Thanks to the help of @makshh this is ultimately what we came up with that worked. This adds a border around the whole table as well as rows/cells, sets the main color of the rows to white, and then colors the "odd" rows with antiquewhite. Hopefully this will help someone else as well.

```
.vtc-table { 
    border: 1px solid #ddd; 
} 
.vtc-table > thead > tr > th, 
.vtc-table > tbody > tr > th, 
.vtc-table > tfoot > tr > th, 
.vtc-table > thead > tr > td, 
.vtc-table > tbody > tr > td, 
.vtc-table > tfoot > tr > td { 
    border: 1px solid #ddd; 
} 
.vtc-table > thead > tr > th, 
.vtc-table > thead > tr > td { 
    border-bottom-width: 2px; 
}
.vtc-table > tbody > tr { 
    background-color: white; 
} 
.vtc-table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
    background-color: #fcf8e3; 
} 
.vtc-table > thead > tr > th, 
.vtc-table > tbody > tr > th, 
.vtc-table > tfoot > tr > th { 
    background-color: #2FA4E7; 
    color: white; 
}
```

And it's called like this in the HTML.

```
<table class="table vtc-table">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `table-striped` class has to be added to the `table` div (you have to use &).
2. Proper selector for striped table is `.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd)`.
3. If you want to change `th` you have to use different selectors (to avoid low specificity).

```
.vtc-table {
  .table;
  .table-condensed;
  .table-bordered; 
  .table-hover;
  &.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
  }
  > thead > tr > th,
  > tbody > tr > th,
  > tfoot > tr > th {
    background-color: #2FA4E7;
    color: white;
  } 
}
```

Comment: This looks like it should work but it's not. I will say that in Visual Studio when I use your code I get the green squiggle by "thead" that says I'm missing a : between the property and value. If I change it to "thead:" it then says "thead" is not a known property. I made sure to clear my browser data as well just to make sure nothing was cached.

Comment: I didn't keep a copy of your original code so I can't see the change but it's not complaining in VS any more. However, it's still not applying any of the .table-striped class. Again, cleared cache just to be on safe side.

Comment: Any errors? I tried to compile this and it works (but without `.table-condensed;`). And what your HTML looks like? `<table class="vtc-table table-striped">`?

Comment: I did F12 to look at the DevTools and didn't see any errors. I also selected a row in the table to inspect it and there isn't any CSS applied to any of the <tr> tags. They simply show as <tr>. I'm calling the class like <table class="vtc-table">.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116822/discussion-between-makshh-and-caverman).